# PlayerPrefs not saving after restart in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a 2d top down shooter and have made the enemies drop coins when they die. I want these coins to save to PlayerPrefs so that the players can use then in the shop. My problem is that the amount of coins isn't saving when the game or editor is restarted. Using the console I was able to narrow the problem down to the PlayerPrefs not saving.

```
public float playerCoins;
private float debugCoins;

void Update()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Bank", playerCoins);
    debugCoins = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Bank");
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    Debug.Log(debugCoins);
```

I used the debugCoins variable and the Debug.Log to check if the variable is initially being saved before restarting the game, which it is.

Comment: This could be a bug from Unity side, if you are on windows though you check whether the ```PlayerPref``` is being saved or not, from Regedit. open Regedit and go to following path ```Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Unity\UnityEditor\<Companey Name>\<Game Name>```

Comment: In general you shouldn't use `PlayerPrefs` in `Update` every frame ... rather make your code event driven and update it also when needed (either when the value is changed or even better: load it once on `Awake` and write it once on `OnApplicationQuit`)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not use save methods on update, and you need to get your Bank on start, because you setting is playerCoins, before it loaded